# Deleting a Facebook Post from a Page with $facebook->api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having trouble deleting a facebook post from my web app. Now I know the [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) and other SO posts say to do this:

```
You can delete objects in the graph by issuing HTTP DELETE requests to 
the object URLs, i.e,

DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/ID?access_token=... HTTP/1.1
```

But since Im such a noob, I dont fully understand the short explanation of deleting with an HTTP request. Since it did not work when I tried, I assume that simply redirecting to the formed url in the example above does not delete anything.  This means theres some new area of web development that I now have to understand... HTTP requests.

How are these done in php? The [php manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.httprequest.php) isnt helping much either.

---

### Additional Information:

I have tried many different variations of:

```
$facebook->api($post_url, 'DELETE', array('method'=> 'delete') );
```

The URL I am passing is `'/post_id'`. The `post_id` is being captured at post creation and stored into the database. This id matched the `$_GET['story_fbid']` that can be found on any post permalink. Perhaps this is not the correct id? I am retrieving the id with the following:

```
//post to wall
$postResult = $facebook->api($post_url, 'post', $msg_body );
//capture the id of the post
$this->fb_post_id = $postResult['id'];
```

When I run the code above, no errors are thrown. It is being touched because a diagnostic `echo` after it is running.

These are the different combinations of strings I have passed to api with `$post_url`:

```
/postid                  api returns true, nothing is deleted from Facebook
/userid_postid           api returns false, Error: (#100) Invalid parameter
/postid_userid           api returns false, Error: (#1705) : Selected wall post for deletion does not exist
/accesstoken_postid      api returns false, Error: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist 
/postid_accestoken       api returns false, Error: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer:

Based on your comment "this is a page" I had a look at the [Graph API's Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) details. If I understand the details right, **Delete is unsupported for [Page Posts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#posts)**. Each connection in the details (Events, Posts, Question etc) have a Create section and if the Connection supports Delete it has a Delete description. The Posts (to feed) section only mentions Create, not Delete.

Comment: All posts were created with my app.

Comment: I have been using `publish_stream` permissions (and `manage_pages` because this is a page). I tried the `POST` method you described and got the following error `Error: Unsupported post request`.

Comment: It looks like you are right. It mentions nothing of Delete and says this in the Unpublished post section: `Unpublishing a post is not supported`. Ill leave this open for a few days just in case someone has a hack for it, but it looks like you'll be getting the check. Thanks for saving me from an unproductive all-nighter

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
$facebook->api("/YOUR_POST_ID","DELETE");
```

will return a boolean value, true if successed and false if failed.

Try prepending userid to the object ID when deleting, like:

```
$facebook->api("/USER-ID_YOUR-POST-ID","DELETE");
```

like:

```
$facebook->api("/12345132_5645465465454","DELETE");
//where 12345132 is fb userid and
//5645465465454 is object id --> post id
```

Comment: For some reason this does not work for me. It returns true but does not delete anything on the page. How is the post id being captured? Please see the additional information I added to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I have had success deleting posts from a page using the page access token with read_stream and manage_pages permissions.

```
try {

        $args = array(
                  'access_token' => $page_token
                );

        $deleted = $facebook->api('/'.$post_id, 'DELETE', $args);

} catch (FacebookApiException $e) { 

            echo 'Delete review page wall error: ' . $e->getType() . ' ' . $e->getMessage();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "unpublish" a post but this isn't the same as deleting a post. Deleting a post is quite easy.

You only need to get the COMMENT_ID and post it to Facebook.

```
 $post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'. $COMMENT_ID .'?access_token=' .  $page_access_token . '&method=delete';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

To clarify this: this works outside of the Page API if you have the rights to manage the posts.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to delete post from page using php SDK 5.4 using this

```
$post = $fb->request('DELETE', '/'.$post_id,[], $page['accesstoken'])
```